# Not able to open DVD tray in brand new MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I just bought a brand new 13" MacBook Pro, i5 2.3 GHz, running Mac OS X 10.6.7.

I'm not able to open the DVD tray of my Mac. I have tried pressing down the <kbd>⏏</kbd> key in the top right corner several times, as well as <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⏏</kbd>, but no success.

Is there some defect with this MacBook Pro or is there some other way to open the DVD tray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a DVD in the drive in the drive you want to eject?

MacBooks use slot drives meaning there is no tray at all, you just push the CD/DVD (gently) into the slot til the drive 'grabs' it and pulls it in ([HT1360](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1360)).

In case you need to eject a disc which doesn't react to the usual means, the following may help (taking more or less verbatim from Apple):

**Ejecting a CD or DVD when all else fails**

- First, quit all applications that are using files on the disc. Then try one of the following alternate methods
- Open Disk Utility (in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder), select the disc, and choose File > Eject.
- Choose Apple menu > Restart and hold down the mouse or trackpad button until the disc ejects.
- Reboot the computer and keep the mouse/trackpad pressed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought there will be a tray that will eject upon press of key like in window based computer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The SuperDrive is slot-loading. You don't open it, but rather slide the CD/DVD into the slog. When you press the eject key, the drive will eject the disc.

Comment: Thanks man. I am new to mac and I thought mac might has a tray which will eject upon pressing eject key. Thanks again you just made my day wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note, since you're coming from the world of CD trays to the slot loading drives:

**Do Not** put oddly shaped CDs in the drive. These are much less common now than they used to be, but the business-card shaped CDs, or half-sized CDs etc.? They don't belong in your drive. It's entirely possible that the mechanism that ejects CDs from your drive won't be able to reach them. Which means a tech having to open up your machine and getting the CD out that way.